# screen sharing software creation using as3

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

I wish to do screen sharing application using as3 as the part of one project.
how to get screen sharing video using as3. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AS3 does not support this per se. There are some [solutions that use java](http://www.jakehilton.com/?q=node/58) or other technologies to stream through a streaming media server such as Flash Media Server (I'm guessing [Fuze Meetings](http://www.fuzemeeting.com/) uses something like this), but you cannot do this with just the Flash Player alone. Adobe's [Connect Now](http://www.adobe.com/acom/connectnow/) supports some screen sharing through their Acrobat.com service.

Comment: thnk u..Do u knw any screen caputre freeware?

Comment: As I understood it; Connect & ConnectNow use some "hidden / undocumented / unexposed" APIs to enable the screen sharing piece. Even with a server, Flash would need access to the screen; which it doesn't have.

Comment: This is no longer the most valid answer.

Answer (score 3):

Screen sharing with flash is already possible with [LiveCycle Collaboration Service](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/livecycle/collaboration.html). Read [this article](http://www.flashrealtime.com/screen-sharing-in-flash-now-available/) for more info

Update: 
[LiveCycle Collaboration Service](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/livecycle/collaboration.html) is now known as [Influxis Collaboration Service](http://ics.influxis.com/)

Answer (score 0):

ScreenCamera SDK is definitily your best option here. It installs a camera on the system just like a regular webcam to which you can connect using Flex. ScreenCamera SDK remains completely invisibe to the end user so it looks like your app is doing all the video capture and recording and sharing.

You can test it from here:
http://www.pcwinsoft.com/download/slsdk/

I think this is the simplest way to do what you want to do,

Comment: Please don't link directly to a download file. I have altered the link to point to the download directory, because I could not find any page on the website that was about the SDK. If you know of such a page, please edit the link to that. Also, if you are affiliated with this product or website, please note that you should include a disclaimer to that effect, as well.